# How do I access a public String that's initialized in my Main Class from an FXML Controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

In my main class I have

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public String versionNumber = "v2.1";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        // SETTING UP THE STAGE
        Stage window;
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Support Tool " + versionNumber);


        // SETTING UP THE SCENES
        Parent parentNewCallDetails = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("newCallDetails.fxml"));
        Scene scnNewCallDetails = new Scene (parentNewCallDetails, 800, 600);

        // CHOOSING THE SCENE AND SHOWING THE STAGE
        window.setScene(scnNewCallDetails);
        window.show();

    }

}
```

I essentially want to be able to access String versionNumber from within the following code in my FXML controller where I set the title of the next scene that I'm launching

```
public class newCallController {

    // ACTION COMPLETED WHEN CALL BUTTON IS PRESSED
    public void btnCall(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {

        // TODO LAUNCH THE NEXT CALL WINDOW
        Parent fxmlMainCallWindow = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainCallWindow.fxml"));
        Scene scnMainCallWindow = new Scene(fxmlMainCallWindow, 1000, 800);

        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ACCESS THE VERSIONNUMBER STRING
        window.setTitle("Support Tool " + versionNumber);
        window.setScene(scnMainCallWindow);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a Constants class with static string param. You can use it anywhere. Like: Constants.VERSION

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String VERSION = "v2.1";
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!